# characteristic polynomial of a nilpotent matrix

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know the characteristic polynomial for a nilpotent matrix is $\lambda ^n$. Is this only true for algebraically closed fields, or any arbitrary field? If so, what is the proof for an arbitrary field?

Proof I have is

$N^r = 0$ for some $r$

$Nx = \lambda x$
for $x \neq 0$

Apply $N$ to both sides $r-1$ times

$N^r x = \lambda ^r x$

therefore eigenvalue is 0.

Thus the characteristic polynomial is $\lambda ^ n$

Which I believe only works for algebraically closed fields

Comment: that indeed only works in algebraically closed fields

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks. so if lambda ^ n is the characteristic polynomial for only algebraically closed fields, can we not say anything about the char poly for arbitrary fields?

Comment: Oh, sorry: the proof only works for algebraically closed fields.  The statement is generally true, though.  The easiest proof is to just consider the same matrix within the algebraic closure, and note that the characteristic polynomials have to be the same.

Comment: You could say that the proof you've given is "basically right" for non-algebraically closed fields because every field *has* an algebraic closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $N^r=0$ for some $r$, the minimal polynomial of $N$ — which exists over any field —  is a divisor of $x^r$, hence is $x^s$ for some $s\le r$.

Now the characteristic polynomial has the same irreducible factors as the minimal polynomial, hence it is $x^t$ for some $t\ge s$.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that the field is algebraically closed. Let $F$ be a field and let $f(X)\in F[X]$ be a polynomial. Then it's easy to construct by induction an extension field $K$ of $F$ where $f$ splits into linear factors.

To wit, take an irreducible factor $g_1$ of $f$. Then $F_1=F[X]/(g_1(x))$ is an extension field of $F$ where $g$ has a root $\alpha_1$. Write $f(X)=(X-\alpha_1)f_1(X)$ and repeat starting from an irreducible factor of $f_1$. Since the degree of $f_1$ is less than the degree of $f$, the process will stop.

If $f(X)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $N$, take the extension field $K$ built as before. The polynomial $f$ has its roots in $K$, but these roots are necessarily $0$, using the argument you showed.